# Will shutting off water to house hurt a water softener?

Tags: water-softener

Will shutting off the water supply to the house hurt a water softner?

Comment: Certainly the makers of the water softener anticipated that at some point, it may lose its water supply, either through purposeful action or natural disaster?  Have you checked the owner's manual?  There may steps you should take when shutting off or turning on the water.